# How to show external images in the same folder as the SSRS report in Design Mode?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hi I am using SQL Server Data Tools 2012 to create SSRS (.rdl) reports. I inserted an image that is external rather than embedded and the actual image file is put right next to the .rdl file within the same local harddrive folder.

The issue is in Design mode, the image does not show. Then in Preview mode, the image does not show either until I copy it to the bin\Debug folder.

The above is annoying as the report and image showing is perfectly fine when they are both deployed onto the Report server under the same path.

Any way to make the image shows in Design mode and tell the SSDT to act smart to copy the image file to the Debug folder?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the full path name to the image? You shouldn't need to have to place them in the same folder.

Comment: @HannoverFist nope, just the filename by itself. Can't use full path as at that end that will have to be deployed onto SSRS server.

Answer (score 1):

Is your image uploaded on the report server as well?

If yes, you could get it to work in both preview mode and when it is deployed using the following expression

```
=IIf(Globals!ReportServerUrl = nothing, "http://YourServer/ReportServer", Globals!ReportServerUrl) + "?%2fImage%2fYourLogo.png"
```

This example assumes you have an image name "YourLogo.png", located in the "Image" folder in the Report Server.

In Visual Studio, Globals!ReportServerUrl is null so this expression uses your actual Report Server URL to locate the image.

Comment: Thanks I shall try that. And I just checked with the help doc. it said local relative path is actually not supported in design mode, hence I will have to upload the image to the server.

Comment: Ok, just tried. So yours solution is for both preview mode and deployment. Still I am missing something for the design mode. But thanks anyway that saved me from copying the images to the Debug/bin folder (in an exchange I have to upload the images to my local server).